# Raspberry pi with self hosted vpn

Tags: pi-4, vpn

I am planning on configuring a self hosted vpn server on my raspberry PI. I am new to networking and was wondering the benefits/downsides of using a self hosted vpn server on a rpi compared to buying a third party vpn. I know one of the main benefits is that you have more control over your data as there is not 3rd party involved. However I was wondering if it was possible to hide your ip address and get an ip address from another country instead? Or is this not possible and only works with 3rd party vpn as they have many servers in different countries?

Comment: `possible to hide your ip address and get an ip address from another country instead` not possible, since **you** only have the one IP address